# Кнопка должна быть сдвинута в нижнюю часть блока с использованием margin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

В общем я пытаюсь написать компонент BannerCard используя React + Typescript .  Кнопка должна находится снизу по центру.

**Вот как оно выглядит**

[image]

**Вот как оно должно смотреться :**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случае 'button' передается как 'children' . Пробовал использовать различные стили  завернув в блок , но без полезно

Это мой 'component.tsx'

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Card } from 'components';
import React, { FC } from 'react';

import { Props } from './props';

const BannerCardBase: FC<Props> = ({ image, children, className, ...rest }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Card className={classNames(className, 'p-3')} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Card>
  );
};
export const BannerCard = styled(BannerCardBase)<Props>`
  ${({ image }) => `
    background-image: url(${image});

  `}
  width: 212px;
  height: 280px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 0;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно например так:

```
<BannerCard >
    <button style={{ position: "relative", top: "180px" }}>Follow</button>
</BannerCard >
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]